# Help! My Campagnolo Record 11 shifters get stuck on my bar tape

Tags: shifter, campagnolo

I have on my rig Campag Athena 11 and Record 11 shifters. Recently, I've noticed the rear gear changing lever, are getting stuck on my bar tape, so when I want to upshift my cassette, I have to flick-off the lever from the bar tape quickly and then push the lever to change gears.
Has anyone had this issue?
Any tips on how to get back to normal shifting? Maybe the angle of movement from rest to shifting can be adjusted back?
Any tips appreciated.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

Sorry I think a picture speaks a 1000 words... this happens when I squeeze the brake lever - not when I am upshifting the rear gears.

[image]

Comment: Has your bartape moved?  Might be time to re-wrap it.   A photo might help users understand your problem.

Comment: I'm guessing the lever wasn't clamped properly or the bar tape slipped. You could try cutting out the relevant part of bar tape or taping it down with some electrical tape a bit tighter. The full solution is probably to take off all the bar tape, make sure the levers are positioned properly and clamped down appropriately to the bar, and then rewrap the bar. But that's a decent amount of work.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have problems shifting to smaller or larger cog?

Comment: @ojs, it only affects me when shifting from small cog to larger cogs, as it's the only lever that allows this. The mouse-ear lever is fine as it's a separate mechanical piece of equipment, as you would know if you knew what Campag gearing is like.

Comment: @Batman, I think the issue is probably that the bar tape has swelled just enough to "catch" the upshift lever (the one just behind the brake lever itself). I'll try and redo the tape or replace it and see what happens

Comment: I have Campagnolo shifters and I have absolutely no idea what is "mouse ear". I guess it's the part I would call "little lever", and it is the one that has interfered with bar tape on my bike. I can't imagine how the upshift lever can be stuck to bar tape, but possible explanations could be misaligned brake levers (the paddle should go slightly past the bars), super sticky bar tape and broken return string.

Comment: @ojs, I've added a picture to illustrate. Sorry should have done this first!

Comment: Have you ever crashed the bike onto that side?  Could be subtly bent, not enough to notice but enough to catch.  Or are there abrasions on the inside ot the little lever that rub on the bartape and provide excessive friction?   Are both brake-hoods level with each other?

Comment: Very thick bar tape? Brake levers adjusted very close to the bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was obvious.

Reset the cable tension on the brakes! Problem solved.

Well in my case I bought new cables and due to the fact I had to take the old ones out and set the new ones with correct pressure settings, the lever does not touch the bar tape anymore.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Excellent spotting and thank you for the completion.